# ActiveMQ 5.16.0 intermittently throwing error on PUT message

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I see intermittent issue when i am trying to put the message to the queue i get below error.

`org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: java.io.EOFException`

I never see this intermittent issue in 5.15.x version.  is there anyone know why I am getting above error?

I also observed this error occurs when I successfully able to PUT and GET the message from queue then i restart ActiveMQ and try to PUT message to queue I get above error. I am using Spring JmsTemplate to create the connection factory and put the message. here is my bean

````
    <bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <!--<constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="queueConnectionFactory"/>
        </constructor-arg>-->
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        </property>
        <!--<property name="defaultDestination" ref="queueDestination" />-->
        <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="MY_QUEUE" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="queueConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory" >
        <property name="brokerURL" > <util:constant static-field="myURL"/></property>
        <property name="keyStore" ref="keystore"/>
        <property name="keyStorePassword" ><util:constant static-field="mypws"/></property>
        <property name="trustStore" ref="truststore"/>
        <property name="trustStorePassword" ><util:constant static-field="mypw"/></property>
        <property name="userName" ><util:constant static-field="user"/></property>
        <property name="password" ><util:constant static-field="pwsd"/></property>
    </bean>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please try this same test using 100% Java JMS code. If the problem persists, open a bug report with [ActiveMQ JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AMQ/issues) and report it against 5.16.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this same test using 100% Java JMS code. If the problem persists, open a bug report with [ActiveMQ JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AMQ/issues) and report it against 5.16.0. If it does not persist, its probably a Spring JMSTemplate and/or wiring configuration issue.

Thanks!